# Correct terminology

Tags: wrapper, adapter

If I wrap class A into class B in order to provide in B certain interface which A doesn't provide (different function names etc), do I call class B a wrapper or a adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both will apply. See also [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

`Facade` would be a good name, if you do more tricks behind the scene like using other classes along with A to create more complex methods.